# Parallel programming in C# how to separate data

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, simulator

At school we started multithreading last week and we already are on multiprocessing now, I am getting a little lost on it so I am going to explain the problem to you.
For an exercise we must make a casino game simulator which simulates 10000 games so that we can know how often the casino wins the game.
So I coded the simulator, and I've got 5 methods to run a game :

```
static void game(Croupier croupier)
{
    croupier.createNewCardDeck();
    croupier.shuffleCards();
    croupier.giveCardsToPlayers();
    croupier.countPlayerPoints();
    croupier.displayResults();
}
```

If I call game in a classic for loop of 10000 iterations it runs ok, takes approx 2 seconds, and the bank wins 50% of times.

If I use Parallel.For, it crashes on shuffleCards, because (I think) multiple processes are trying to edit the same pack of cards at the same time.

My first idea was to put a Mutex on my shuffleCards, but it would slow down the simulation, when the point of using Parallel programming was to increase speed. So I thought to separate data on the different processes ( so that instead of 10000 iterations, I do 2500 on 4 processes, every loop having its own croupier, players, cards etc...)

What do you think would be the best way of resolving this problem ? Have you got any simple tutorial that explains how to deal with parallel work which uses the same data ? Which solution would you choose ?
Thanks

Edit : ShuffleCard method

```
        List<Card> randomList = new List<Card>();

        Random r = new Random();
        int randomIndex = 0;

        while (_cards.Count > 0)
        {
            randomIndex = r.Next(0, _cards.Count); //Choose a random object in the list
            randomList.Add(_cards[randomIndex]); //add it to the new, random list
            _cards.RemoveAt(randomIndex); //remove to avoid duplicates
        }
        return randomList;
```

So yes _cards being a private property of croupier (which calls this._cards = shuffleCards() , every process have the same card list

Comment: Please show us how the shuffleCards is implemented as well, are you using static values? Or are you giving each thread the same croupier?

Comment: But shouldn't it be _different_ data? I would assume that createNewCardDeck() returned an object that could then be passed to shuffleCards().  Each instance of shuffleCards() would then be shuffling its own deck, so you wouldn't have concurrent access problems.

Comment: Actually, your second approach seems sound. You partition the iterations by the logical processor count and then run them in parallel with separate data (if possible). And it's certainly possible in your case - as you noticed.

Comment: createNewCardDeck() creates a new instance of CardDeck class (which in fact contains _cards). Then croupier.cardDeck becomes this new object. But the fact being that croupier is passed to the parallel foreach, I guess all processes are working with the same croupier and therefore with the same card deck. That being said, I would like to know more about how instatiation works in parallel processes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your idea is the way to go: Give each "processing unit" (i.e. thread, task) its own game table (croupier, players, cards). Just like in a real casino you can have as many game tables as you want, playing all at the same time, indepently from each other because they do not share any data. Whenever a game is finished, the results is transferred to the bank (of which you have only one). So the only thing that must be synchronized (with a criticial section) is the aggregation of the results into the bank.

This example is the perfect trivial example for parallel programming, because the real world can rather intuitively be modeled into the corresponding classes and algorithms.

Comment: Sounds right. The shuffle method itself does not seem to have specific issues. Seems that the current solution is sharing one croupier between all processes. Each thread should have its own croupier (and the croupiers have their own deck and players).

Comment: This seems right but how can I say (code speaking) that I want each 2500 iterations on different processes?

Comment: If you really want to control how many games run in parallel, create 4 instances of the class `GameTable` (or `Game` or `Croupier` whatever you think is a better model for a game) and  call `gameTable1.PlayNewGame()`  2500 times in a loop. Each of the 4 loops should be run in a separate task/thread. If you want to pass the responsibilty of deciding how man games are run in parallel to the runtime just use `Parallel.For` or `ParallelForeach` and create a new game for each of the 10000 loops.

Answer (score 0):

Either give each thread it's own set of collections or implement a [concurrent collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) which implements its own thread locking.

Answer (score 0):

> so that instead of 10000 iterations, I do 2500 on 4 processes

Can use Task and Data Parallelism together, For eg,

```
        int noOfProcess = 4;
        Task[] t = new Task[noOfProcess];
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfProcess; i++)
        {
           t[i]= Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Parallel.For(0, 2500, (v) => game(..));
            });
        }
        Task.WaitAll(t); //If Synchronous is needed.
```

Avoid Writing to Shared Memory Locations.Check this msdn for some [pitfalls while using Parallel Programming.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Earlier answers are indeed right, the goal is to split up the work in order to run it as quickly as possible.  In short: design your code to be concurrent, so it can run in parallel.

In each run, we have:

- A croupier
- A game being played
- Only one game per Croupier at one time.
- The results of the game

The two main decisions regarding concurrency we need to make is

- How do we share or distribute Croupiers amongst games?
- How do results get shared?

Here are the different options for the Croupier:

- If we have only one Croupier, we will end up with no concurrency. Only one game can be played at one time.
- We could have one Croupier per game. That way we could theoretically run each game simultaneously.
- We could have one Croupier per processing unit. This would allow as many games to run as possible, but this would may not balance as well as one Croupier per game, as there might be other factors outside of raw processing. Imagine if writing the results was a lengthy IO operation, but not CPU intensive. We could be running more games, but instead the Croupier is waiting for results to finish.

For the results, we could:

- Output results to some stream as we received them. If this is a console, output could easily become garbled.
- Output results to some consumer that processes the results in turn. This is the better option as it allows the result state to be returned without effecting games.

So the overall decision making should always be around: how can I make my code as concurrency friendly as possible, to allow the hosting system to run things as best it can.

For the example below, I have opted for a Croupier per processing unit, not because it is better, but because it was not illustrated in the other answers.

Here is some sample code illustrating some of these ideas:

```
void Main()
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_GAMES = 10000;

    // this is how we have a Croupier per thread.
    var threadLocalCroupier = new ThreadLocal<Croupier>(() => new Croupier());

    var results = from gameNumber in Enumerable.Range(0, NUMBER_OF_GAMES).AsParallel()
                let croupier = threadLocalCroupier.Value
                select game(croupier, gameNumber);

    foreach (var result in results) {
        Console.WriteLine("Game done {0}", result.GameNumber);
        // display or analyse results.
    }
}

static ResultOfGame game(Croupier croupier, int gameNumber)
{
    croupier.createNewCardDeck(gameNumber);
    croupier.shuffleCards();
    croupier.giveCardsToPlayers();
    croupier.countPlayerPoints();
    var results = croupier.getResults();

    return results;
}

class ResultOfGame {

    public int GameNumber { get; private set; }

    public ResultOfGame(int gameNumber) 
    {
        this.GameNumber = gameNumber;
    }

}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Croupier {

private int currentGame;

    public void createNewCardDeck(int gameNumber) {this.currentGame = gameNumber;}
    public void shuffleCards() {}
    public void giveCardsToPlayers() {}
    public void countPlayerPoints() {}
    public ResultOfGame getResults() {
        return new ResultOfGame(this.currentGame);
    }
}
```